# ESB service for extracting a password for a specific username from wso2 IS

Tags: authentication, wso2, esb, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Is it possible to expose a wso2 Identity Server admin service though wso2 ESB?

What I want to do is have an ESB service, that extracts for a certain username its password from the Identity Server (for example using the admin credentials). I know wso2 Identity Server has admin services which I can use, but where can I find detailed description of those and how can I implement this scenario?

Any blogs or tutorials will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blog entry [here](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/10/wsas-hiddedn-services.html) that describes the admin services.

However, I don't expect you will be able to retrieve the password.  The plain text password is probably not stored in the WSO2 server, the hashed value of the password will be stored instead - see [here](http://wso2.org/forum/thread/11958)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I saw those services described there are for wso2 WSAS, are the admin services the same for Identity server? I wouldn't expect the pass to be stored as plain text, but perhaps there is an admin service in the IS that can return it as text?

Comment: If I remember right, I have in the past used [this wsdl](https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl) on the Identity server.  The password is normally stored as a one-way hash meaning that it is possible to create the hash from the password, but impossible to create the password from the hash.